# PHP pushing items to array creates seperate array within array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, array-merge

I have created a function to generate random numbers, which accepts a start number, end number, qunatity of numbers to be generated and also the ability to exclude an array of numbers. It looks like this:

```
function random_numbers($min, $max, $quantity, $exclude) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    $left = array_diff($numbers, $exclude);
    shuffle($left);
    $remain = array_slice($left, 0, $quantity);
    return $remain;
}
```

The exclude array looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 217 [1] => 321 [2] => 1591 [3] => 1069 [4] => 1532 )
```

I then want to merge the newly generated numbers with the exclude array and save it to WordPress post_meta, so i have done the following:

```
$exclude = get_post_meta($product_id, '_numbers_sold', false);

$numbers = random_numbers('1', $max_tickets, $qty, $exclude);

foreach($numbers as $number){
    $exclude [] = $number;
}

update_post_meta($product_id, '_numbers_sold', $sold_numbers);
```

The function works, but pushing the new number to the array creates seperate arrays. I have also tried `array_merge`, but i get the same results.

The output is as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 217
            [1] => 321
            [2] => 1591
            [3] => 1069
            [4] => 1532
        )

    [1] => 597
    [2] => 1853
    [3] => 582
    [4] => 1887
    [5] => 1484
)
```

Why would this be happening? It seperates the two arrays. Is it because the array keys already exist?

Comment: What have you tried so far to resolve the problem? That's so little code that even vardump could help, and if not you can also run XDebug

Comment: Please var_dump and post both `$exclude` and `$numbers` before you attempt to merge them.